# SPI signal translation between Arduino and PIC(8bit microcontroller)

Tags: c, arduino, pic, spi

I'm testing a SPI communication between Arduino UNO and PIC16F1(PC16F1827).

This is my wiring and source code:

MPLAB X IDE 3.55 / XC8 v1.4.1(Free)

```
#include <xc.h>

#pragma config FOSC = INTOSC    // Inner clock
#pragma config WDTE = OFF       // Watchdog timer
#pragma config PWRTE = OFF      // Power-Up timer
#pragma config MCLRE = ON       // MCLR pin
#pragma config CP = OFF         // Code protection
#pragma config CPD = OFF        // Memory protection
#pragma config BOREN = ON       // Brown-out Reset
#pragma config CLKOUTEN = OFF   // Outer clock
#pragma config IESO = OFF       // Oscillator switchover
#pragma config FCMEN = OFF      // Fail-Safe clockmonitor

#pragma config WRT = OFF        // Power-up Timer
#pragma config PLLEN = ON       // Use 4xPLL
#pragma config STVREN = OFF     // Reset when stack error
#pragma config LVP = OFF        // Low voltage program

#define _XTAL_FREQ 32000000 // 32MHz

void main(void)
{
    // PIC initialization
    OSCCON = 0b00110100; // Inner clock = 4Mhz

    ANSELA = 0b00000000; // All RA are digital
    TRISA = 0b00000001; // RA0 is input
    PORTA = 0b00000000; // Initialize RA

    // SPI initalization
    SDO1SEL = 0; // RB2 sets to SDO pin
    SSP1CON1 = 0b00100101; // Slave mode(Unuse SS)
    SSP1STAT = 0b01000000; // Slave mode(Clock phase is LOW)

    SSP1BUF = 0;

    unsigned char read_data; // Current is dummy
    unsigned char count = 255;
    while(1){
        // Read byte from master
        read_data = SSP1BUF;       
        while(!SSP1STATbits.BF);

        // Write byte to master
        if(count == 255) count = 0; else count++;
        SSP1BUF = count;
        while(!SSPSTATbits.BF);
    }
}
```

Arduino IDE 1.8.1

```
#include <SPI.h>

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);

  SPI.begin() ;
  SPI.setBitOrder(MSBFIRST) ;
  SPI.setDataMode(SPI_MODE1) ;

  delay(1500) ;
}

void loop()
{
  char msg[100];
  byte i, n;

  for (i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++) {
    n = SPI.transfer(i) ;

    sprintf(msg, "%d/%d,", n, i);
    Serial.print(msg);
  }

  Serial.print("\n");
}
```

[image: Wiring image]

My ideal is that Arduino receives the value of 0-255(I have ignored about frequency of SPI because it's a programming test). But SPI.transfer() returns a value of i(0-9).

I worry about where I should fix because there is little technical information of those IC on the web. Does someone know the good way?

Comment: I don't think there is "little information on those IC". With a scope you could see what is happening. Anyway, don't post a photo of the wiring - describe it instead. Are you sure it's correct?

Comment: I wired according to a datasheet. If you think that is wrong, please tell me the detail.

Comment: No, you should give details.

Comment: I changed the circuit image according to your advice.

Comment: I suggest you use the XC8 SPI peripheral library and look up examples online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a look at the PIC 16F1826 datasheet to check your connections.

The pin used to transmit out data from SPI1 , named SDO1, can be RA6 or RB2 (from datasheet, page 12 [Table 1-2]).

Given that you write 0 to SDO1SEL (it's already 0 on reset), SDO1 appears to be on RB2. In fact, you connected RB2 and not RA6.

*But you don't clear the corresponding TRISB bit to make RB2 an output*, as stated in page 236 (chapter 25.2.2). Your current program can not transmit data out of RB2/SDO1.

Maybe there are other errors too, probably in setting up registers. I advice to read carefully the datasheet and revise all your settings on the PIC side. Then, if you have still problems, update your question and I will update my answer (leave a comment to wake me). For example, I didn't check that your connection from RB2 goes to the right place of Arduino (I see it goes to pin 11, but I didn't check it is correct: like some compilers, I stop on the first error).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'll check this post is answer when I had to run the program.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed wiring(MISO to MISO, MOSI to MOSI, connect SS).

[image: Fixed wiring]

And I changed the program on PIC16F1. It appends initialize RB pins and signal receives as an interrupt.

```
unsigned char count = 0;

void interrupt OnInterSpi()
{
    if (SSP1IF == HIGH){
        SSP1IF = LOW;

        unsigned char read_data = SSP1BUF;
        if(count == 255) count = 0; else count++;
        SSP1BUF = count;
    }
}

void main(void)
{
    OSCCON = 0b00110100;    

    ANSELA = 0b00000000;    
    TRISA = 0b00000001;     
    PORTA = 0b00000000;     


    ANSELB = 0b00000000;
    TRISB = 0b00010010;     
    PORTB = 0b00000000;     

    SDO1SEL = 0;             
    SSP1CON1 = 0b00100100;    
    SSP1STAT = 0b01000000;    

    SSP1IF = 0;  
    SSP1IE = 1;  
    PEIE = 1;   
    GIE = 1;   

    while(1) ;
}
```

On Arduino, I enabled SS signal.

```
#include <SPI.h>

#define SS_PIN 10

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);

    pinMode(SS_PIN, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(SS_PIN, HIGH);

    SPI.begin();
    SPI.setBitOrder(MSBFIRST);
    SPI.setDataMode(SPI_MODE0);
}

char msg[100];
byte i, n;

void loop()
{
    digitalWrite(SS_PIN, LOW);
    n = SPI.transfer(i);
    digitalWrite(SS_PIN, HIGH);

    sprintf(msg, "%d/%d, ", n, i);
    Serial.print(msg);
}
```

Received values increased correctly on the serial monitor of Arduino at least  in my environment.

Comment: I'm happy you solved. And I like your beautiful drawings about wiring, but I think that a text description like "RB2 <-> ArdSS", or "Pic.12 <-> Ard.13" is more suited in this cases :-)